# Preserving old links on new WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, google-search

It is a simple scenario. The client wanted a remake of an old site and we chose WordPress. Besides visual redesign there were changes in content structure and naturally links. The problem is that the old content is pretty highly ranked on Google, so the questions is actually two fold.

- Will switching to new site affect the ranking?
- How to preserve links that are already there on Google to point to the same content but to different URL's on the new site?

Comment: You should probably ask this over at wordpress.stackexchange.com  - It may be more on topic there.

Comment: And if I asked how to implement 301 redirects in PHP on WP platform then it would be OK I guess? Stanford experiment comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching will affect your Google rankings.  The ranking is tied to the address of a page, so when you move it to a new address, you loose the ranking you've built up.  However, if you use 301 redirects from the old content to the new, you will *preserve* your Google rankings.  This tells the search engine that your content that was in page A is now in page B.  Think "change of address" cards for the Internet.  It works for search engines as well as users in browsers.

Here's a good article on the subject:  http://www.bruceclay.com/blog/2007/03/how-to-properly-implement-a-301-redirect/